# Proper way to catch errors other than network issues in fetch() call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, fetch

The route of my `fetch()` call can yield two possible responses for which I want to do different things. But the `catch()` of `fetch()` only catches network errors [if I'm not mistaken](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Below is my current code, but it looks strange to me and I have the feeling there's a more proper way to do it. If so, what is it?

```
fetch(`${this.baseUrl}/wp-json/contact/v1/send`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
})
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.status === 304) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something different
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Comment: There's a really nice wrapper library  [wretch](https://github.com/elbywan/wretch) that allows you to chain the various status callbacks

Comment: Code looks entirely reasonable. If you wanted some/all 300 series status codes to be treated as error(s) then you could detect them and throw an Error from the `then()` handler ... it would be caught by the `catch()` clause. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using `async` `await` you could use the classic `try...catch...finally`

```
try {
    await fetch(`${this.baseUrl}/wp-json/contact/v1/send`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
          })

} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
} finally {
    console.log('We do cleanup here');
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't look better and also where are the separate response codes?

Comment: @drake035 this is a correct answer, you also can get the response in the `catch` by using `console.log(e.response)` with axios at least. But probably with `fetch` too.

Comment: This one may help: https://gist.github.com/odewahn/5a5eeb23279eed6a80d7798fdb47fe91